# Dropdown menu hover issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

https://www.pamdidner.com/category/announcement/ If you hover the mouse under the About item (where submenu is supposed to be) it will show the drop down menu. But this is not very convenient if you need to click some content, which is located in that area.

https://pdidner.staging.wpengine.com/category/announcement/ As you see on the staging server everything works fine and the submenu only appears when you hover the About item.

Tried disabling plugins, deleting all the customly added css/js but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: they look the same to me. what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm on Chrome, hovered the menu on both sites, behaves the same/fine. Maybe try clearing your cache?

Comment: Chrome/Firefox Try to hover the About menu item. 

On the second link you need to hover exactly the 'About' word to see the dropdown. 

On the first link you can put your mouse 120px under the About and you will still see it.

Comment: Ah I gotcha. It's broken on both sites.

Comment: It's because you're using `opacity` and `visibility`. One fix would be to remove `position: relative` from the `li.menu-item` (you have that declared in a couple of CSS entries), and add `li.menu-item:hover { position: relative; }`. But that screws up the menu layout when you un-hover. I would handle it with javascript instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
.sub-menu{
display:none;
}
.menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu{
display:block;
}
```

hope this helps..